# Why is this R version of Knight's Tour not working?

Tags: r, oop, knights-tour

I'm new to R and I'm trying to find the least number of moves it takes for the knight to move around a chess board when it starts from the corner.

I used the Python algorithm from this website:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-knights-tour-problem-backtracking-1/

and I tried to translate it to R.

However, when I run the program, its output is:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[2,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[3,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[4,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[5,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[6,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[7,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[8,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[1] "Minimum number of moves:  -1"
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

This is the code:

```
chess = rep(-1, times = 64)
board = matrix(data = chess, nrow = 8, ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE)

move_x = c(2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2)
move_y = c(1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1)
board[1, 1] = 0
pos = 1

valid_move <- function (x, y, board) {
    if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= 8 && y <= 8 && board[x, y] == -1) {
        return (T)
    }
    return (F)
}   

solve <- function (board, curr_x, curr_y, move_x, move_y, pos) {
    
    if (pos == 64) {
        return (T)
    }
    for (i in seq(1, 8)) {
        new_x = curr_x + move_x[i]
        new_y = curr_y + move_y[i]

        if (valid_move(new_x, new_y, board)) {
            board[new_x, new_y] = pos
            if (solve(board, new_x, new_y, move_x, move_y, (pos+1))) {
                return (TRUE)
            }
            board[new_x, new_y] = -1
        }
    }
    return (F)
}

main <- function() {
    sims = 10
    ctr = 0
    number_of_moves = c()

    solve(board, 1, 1, move_x, move_y, pos)



    for (x in board) {
        for (y in board) {
            number_of_moves <- c(number_of_moves, board[x, y])
        }
    }
    print(board)
    print(paste("Minimum number of moves: ", min(number_of_moves)))
}


main()
```

Comment: You have two different `board`s: one is in the global scope and the other is passed through the functions. The global one is not changed by the `solve` function. If you add a `print(board)` inside the `if (pos == 64) { ... }` clause, you can see the final state of the board that you pass through the functions. Changing the global board from inside a function can be done via `board[new_x, new_y] <<- -1` for example.

Comment: I don't think this is 'proper' S4 OOP, can someone post a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, when a function makes changes to one of its arguments, it only makes changes to a local copy, not the original variable.

For example, in this R snippet, we can see the function doesn't actually modify the variable `l`.

```
try_to_modify <- function(l) l[[1]] <- -100

l <- list(1)
try_to_modify(l)
l
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
```

Contrast this to python, where it actually *does* modify `l`.

```py
# (python code)
def try_to_modify(l):
  l[0] = -100

l = [1]
try_to_modify(l)
l
#> [-100]
```

If you want a function to communicate somthing to the caller, it either needs to modify a global variable (which generally isn't the best solution), or it needs to use the return value. (There are some exceptions, but that's generally how it works).

So instead of returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you can return `board` or `NULL`.

```
valid_move <- function (x, y, board) {
  x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= 8 && y <= 8 && board[x, y] == -1
}

solve <- function (board, curr_x, curr_y, move_x, move_y, pos) {
  if (pos == 64) {
    return (board)
  }
  for (i in seq(1, 8)) {
    new_x = curr_x + move_x[i]
    new_y = curr_y + move_y[i]
    
    if (valid_move(new_x, new_y, board)) {
      board[new_x, new_y] = pos
      result <- solve(board, new_x, new_y, move_x, move_y, (pos + 1))
      if (!is.null(result)) {
        return (result)
      }
      board[new_x, new_y] = -1
    }
  }
  # Return NULL
  # As this is the last result of the function, you don't need to write `return (NULL)`
  NULL
}
```

```
final_board <- solve(
  board = matrix(
    c(0, rep_len(-1, 63)),
    nrow = 8,
    ncol = 8,
    byrow = TRUE
  ),
  curr_x = 1,
  curr_y = 1,
  move_x = c(2, 1,-1,-2,-2,-1, 1, 2),
  move_y = c(1, 2, 2, 1,-1,-2,-2,-1),
  pos = 1
)

final_board
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#> [1,]    0   59   38   33   30   17    8   63
#> [2,]   37   34   31   60    9   62   29   16
#> [3,]   58    1   36   39   32   27   18    7
#> [4,]   35   48   41   26   61   10   15   28
#> [5,]   42   57    2   49   40   23    6   19
#> [6,]   47   50   45   54   25   20   11   14
#> [7,]   56   43   52    3   22   13   24    5
#> [8,]   51   46   55   44   53    4   21   12
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! I was just wondering what the difference is between return result and return board? Also, I added a print statement to final_board because there was no output haha

Comment: `board` is the current board. `result` is the "next" board - the result from calling `solve` again. When `return (board)` is called, that is the base case. When `result <- solve(...)` is called, that is the recursive case.